# pandas to.csv method doubles all '\'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

so i am trying to save a dataframe to csv using the pandas library
for some reason the to_csv pandas method is changing the directory i am referring to...

```
A = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
B = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

df = percentile_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {'lst1Title': A,
     'lst2Title': B})
print(df)
ticker_name = "AAPL"
path = fr'C:\Users\my_name\Documents\python projects\my_project\{ticker_name}_stock-price.csv'
print(path)
df.to_csv(path)
```

it tells me that the directory does not exist...
beyond that pycharm marks the "path" string in the to_csv line and says "Expected type 'None', got 'str' instead "
while i know that the to_csv method can handle strings... any one?

first part was answered so i edited it out... any one can help with whats left?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of it adding a backslashes to your path is normal as it is resolving the path and is returning an escaped string.

Just adjust your `path` variable like so and try again:

```
path = fr'C:\Users\my_name\Documents\python projects\my_project\{ticker_name}_stock-price.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the OS agonstic file path concatenation to avoid path separator issues where every subfolder is specified in comma-separated elements with base file at the end.

```
import os

...
path = os.path.join(
    "C:", "Users", "my_name", "Documents", "python projects", 
    "my_project",  "f{ticker_name}_stock-price.csv"
)
```